How to activate tree view in Nautilus on Ubuntu 24.04?
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04 and I'm trying to activate a tree view in Nautilus (Files) similar to other file managers. I have searched online and thought about installing Nautilus extensions or GNOME Shell Extensions through terminal commands sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions, but as a new Ubuntu user I would prefer to ask the community first.
Could someone please guide me on how to enable a tree view in Nautilus on Ubuntu 24.04? If there’s a specific extension or method that works for this version, I would appreciate detailed steps or alternative suggestions.
Thank you!
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble
$ nautilus --version
GNOME nautilus 46.1


It depends on what you understand under a "tree view". Perhaps you refer to the display of the tree of folders in the left file pane. Nautilus does not have such feature. In the left pane, file locations are displayed.
However, Nautilus has a feature where in the main pane, folders can be expanded while in list view. This then provides a "tree view" along with the files.

In "Prefences", check "Expandable folders in list view".
Switch to "list view": hit the shortcut key Ctrl+1 or click the one but last icon on the right to change view to "list view".

Now, each folder has an arrow on the left side that, when clicked, expands the folder and files beneath. With the keyboard, you can use right and left arrows to expand and contract the current folder.
As before, double clicking a folder or hitting Enter while the cursor is on a folder "zooms in" into that folder.
